# Gobi 2000 WWAN Adapter C# SDK

Tags: c#, wifi, 3g

We have some software running on Windows 7 on a mobile device (Panasonic Toughbook) which needs to initiate a 3g connection to download data.

The WWAn adapter in question is a Gobi 2000. Is there any way of controlling the adapter direct from .net or should we fall back on Windows to initiate the connection as required (battery life is important).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I just started a project for the Toughbook and I'm also looking for how to control the Gobi adapter and read signal strength.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the SDK from http://www.gobianywhere.com/node/add/developers-sdk

Haven't tried it to see how good it is yet.

Comment: Hello, we have the same case. However, I need the gobi SDK even if it is c++. I don't know where to download it.